# How to return a Boolean from @ReactMethod in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to return a Boolean from @ReactMethod in reactNative Android application.

But when I make method similar to

```
@ReactMethod
public boolean retBoolean() {
return true;
}
```

and call it from JS component ,it returns undefined.
only when return type is void function gets called ,I am not able to return string or boolean.

Answer (score 29):

Rather than using callback, you could also use `Promise`.

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;

@ReactMethod
public void hasFlash(final Promise promise) {
    Camera camera = RCTCamera.getInstance().acquireCameraInstance();
    if (null == camera) {
        promise.reject("No camera found.");
        return;
    }
    List<String> flashModes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
    promise.resolve(null != flashModes && !flashModes.isEmpty());
}
```

Then in your JS, call it with

```
const myFunction = async () => { 
    const hasFlash = await CameraManager.hasFlash(); 
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution

Comment: Oh so How to call return function in javascript and get value return in android native?

Comment: how is it better than providing simple callback and then invoking it with the result ?

Answer (score 25):

According to react documentation

> To expose a method to JavaScript a Java method must be annotated using @ReactMethod. The return type of bridge methods is always void. React Native bridge is asynchronous, so the only way to pass a result to JavaScript is by using callbacks or emitting events

So if you want to return some value like boolean or string you need to use callbacks.

Example:

```
@ReactMethod
public void isEqual(
        int a,
        int b,
        Callback booleanCallback) {
    boolean equal= a == b;
    booleanCallback.invoke(equal);
}
```

In javascript call like below...

```
YourClass.isEqual(
 5,
 10,
 (status) => {
  console.log('Result ',status);
 }
);
```

For more info refer [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#callbacks)

Comment: If we wanted to use the return value in our code other than `console.log`, how would we go about this? E.g. `setState({myStatus:status})` Is this possible with the callback functionality or is it better to go with a Promise as outlined below?

Answer (score 1):

In ReactNative 0.67.5 you can use `isBlockingSynchronousMethod` attribute property of `ReactMethod`:

```
// Kotlin
@ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
fun isFoo(): Boolean {
  return true
}

// JS
consoleLog(`isFoo: ${NativeModules.Foo.isFoo()}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String.valueOf(variable)
```

I wasted time to identify what is going on. In java logs result was ok but returned results in RN was always false. converting boolean to string solved the issue. You can cast the string "true", "false" into boolean in React Native.

```java
@ReactMethod
private void foo(Promise promise){
    boolean boo = true;
    String str = String.valueOf(boo);
    promise.resolve(str);
}
```